# combineReducers not outputting as an object

Tags: object, redux

I'm importing my reducers as follows `import reducers from './reducers/index';` and using it inside the store `const store = createStore(reducers);`

**index.js**

Inside my index file I have `import {combineReducers} from 'redux';` and I'm exporting as follows:

```
export default combineReducers({
  obj: objsReducers,
  objKop: objKopsReducers
})
```

Also I'm importing my required files from folders.

But still in my console logs, I'm outputting arrays, instead of objects. I want it to output as an object because isn't that what combineReducer is meant to do in Redux?

Like so, `{objs: {…}, objkop: {…}}`

Maybe a better question is: Does it matter if it outputs as an array?

Comment: Please post the snippet of code where you are calling the `console.log`. The `combineReducers` method also performs a check on each of the reducers, so it's possible they don't satisfy the requirements of a redux reducer.

Comment: @DannyDelott Thanks for your reply. This is my console log: `store.subscribe(function() {
    console.log('current state is: ', store.getState());
})` Should I have square brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as an official documentation says it should return:

```
Returns
(Function): A reducer that invokes every reducer inside the reducers object, and constructs a state object with the same shape.
```

You are doing it in a correct way, so I would suggest you continue with it and add a test action to test it properly.